# Select all content when Tabulator editor opens

Tags: tabulator

I have a Tabulator (4.9.3) with values that use an editor of type text. As I tab through the table, I want each value to be selected so I can overwrite it without having to clear it first. I have tried putting the usual range selection code into the cellEditing callback and the Tabulator source code where the input gets created. Here is one variation of the code (I can't show them all because the node differs based on context):

```
try {
    if (document.selection) {
        // IE
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(input);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(input);
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
} catch (e) {console.log(e);}
```

If I double-click on the cell, the value selects as desired. How can I get this to work with keyboard navigation as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the editor is not assigned an id, finding a selector that could find it reliably was problematic without editing the source code. Since I was going to have to edit the source, I ended up adding the following line to the onRendered function of the input element under Edit.prototype.editors.

```
input.select();
```